# Django - Check if newer value exist for each item in queryset

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have a model that hold the users reactions and I have few types of reactions - 1,2,3,4.
The user can react few times with different values and I want to keep them in the DB.
This is my model (I'm using Generic Foreign Key, not sure if it matters).

```
class Reaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Reaction date", auto_now_add=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name=_('content type'),
                                     related_name="content_type_for_%(class)s", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    root_obj = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
    react = models.CharField('Reaction', max_length=10)
```

I want to get all the the root_obj (distinct if possible) that the user reacted with specific reaction (e.g. 2), but not with a reaction of type 3,4 afterwards.

Is it possible?
Thanks

R

Comment: Do you mean something like `Reaction.objects.filter(user=request.user, react='2').only('root_obj').distinct()`?

Comment: I don't think so. I want to get the root_obj only if there weren't reaction with react=3,4 afterwards

Comment: so, in pseudocode, if reaction = 2 and there is not reaction = 3 and reaction = 4 for that same user, then give me the root_obj. Otherwise, return nothing?

Comment: almost - if reaction = 2 and there is not **later** reaction = 3 and reaction = 4 for that same user, then give me the root_obj.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did this correctly. See if it works:

```
def view(request, object_pk):
query = Reaction.objects.filter(user=request.user, object_pk=object_pk) \
                        .only('react', 'date', 'root_obj')

try:                       
    react2 = query.get(react='2')
except:
    react2 = None

try:                       
    react3 = query.get(react='3')
except:
    react3 = None

try:                       
    react4 = query.get(react='4')
except:
    react4 = None

# Is there a reaction = 2 and not a reaction = 3 or 4?
if react2 and not react3 or not react4:
    return react2.root_obj

# Is there a reaction = 3 or 4 along with 2?
elif react2 and react3 or react4:

    if react3:

        if react2.date < react3.date:
            return react2.root_obj
        return None
    elif react4:

        if react2.date < react4.date::
            return react2.root_obj
        return None
return None
```

Comment: Sorry, but I guess I wasn't clear enough...
I need the all the root_obj that their latest reaction is 2. 
Your code only returns the latest for all root_obj together, right?

Comment: @Rani Not quite sure I follow I'm sorry. My code returns the root_obj is their reaction = 2 AND there are no recent reactions equal to 3 or 4.

Comment: It looks like your code returns single root_obj, but sometimes I can find more than one root_obj that answer those conditions.